# PHP Unify duplicate array

Tags: php, arrays

in my PHP code I have many array like this:

```
0 = ['attr_id':1,'name':'qty','value':'100'];
1 = ['attr_id':1,'name':'qty','value':'200'];
2 = ['attr_id':1,'name':'qty','value':'500'];
3 = ['attr_id':2,'name':'price','value':'10$'];
```

I want merge this array like this:

```
0 = ['attr_id':1,'name':'qty','value':['100','200','500']];
1 = ['attr_id':1,'name':'price','value':'10$'];
```

can you guys help me please?
thanks

Comment: `attr_id':1` on both? Typo? Have you tried looping or anything else?

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: @AbraCadaver no, your solution works for me. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simpler.  Build the result using the `attr_id` as the index and append the `value`:

```
foreach($array as $values) {
    $result[$values['attr_id']]['value'][] = $values['value'];
    $result[$values['attr_id']] = $result[$values['attr_id']] + $values;
}
```

If you need to reindex, just use `array_values()` on the `$result`.

Answer (score 1):

This is one method where you loop through an array_column array of the id's and use key to insert values from values array.

```
$value = array_column($arr, 'value');
$id = array_column($arr, 'attr_id');
$res =[];

Foreach($id as $key => $i){
    If(!isset($res[$i])) $res[$i] = ['attr_id' => $i, 'name'=>'qty', 'value' => []];
    $res[$i]['value'][] = $value[$key];
}
Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/VXI5E

As you see I use the id as key to keep track of the result array.
If you want to clear this, meaning reset the counting from 0, use array_values.

```
$res = array_values($res);
```

Edit: also the 10$ is inside an array in my answer, this makes it easier to use the array later in my opinion.
If you must save it as an string I can fix it, but it will probably be harder to use the array later with a mixed item.